# Fetch and Filter data using a valid ID

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How it should work.

Input bar with select values

value 1,2,3,4 etc...

If I select value 1, it should fetch the data that has Id 1 and then map/filter this data plus the other arrays.

The data that can only be fetched if a valid Id is used. The Id is the parameter that must be used in the API call otherwise it will read undefined. How do I map this to the select values if no data is there without it?

```
{
    "localPm": {
        "id": 40001,
        "name": "John",
        
    },
    "past": [
        {
            "id": 40005,
            "name": "David",
            
        }
    ],
    "present": [],
    "future": [],
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/test/test/test?Id=1"  
        }
    }
}
```

This is the id i need -

```
"_links": {
            "self": {
                "href": "http://localhost:8080/test/test/test?Id=1"  
            }
```

This is the fetch

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchReports = async () => {
      try {
        if (selectedEngagementId !== null) { // Check for a valid selected engagement ID
          const { _links } = await StaffReportDataService.getStaffingReport(selectedEngagementId);// this is an import of the api call and the function within

          console.log("API Response:", _links.values); // Debugging
          setGetData(_links.values);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching reports:", error);
      }
    };
  
    if (selectedEngagementId !== null) {
      fetchReports();
    }
```

Comment: Didn't get this " How do I map this to the select values if no data is there without it?" Can you put a UI screenshot